# Need a mysql case statement that checks a cell

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join, right-join

I currently have 2 tables, lets say Table_A contains hundreds of sandwiches along with info about them and pictures, and Table_B contains specific sandwich groups. For example:

Table_A will have 4 columns:

- Column 1 "id" which is auto-incrementing
- Column 2 "sandwich_name" which contains Meatball sandwich 1, Meatball Sandwich 2, Meatball Sandwich 3, Turkey Sandwich 1, etc
- Column 3 "sandwich type", in this case would be Meatball Sandwich, Meatball Sandwich, Meatball Sandwich, Turkey Sandwich
- Column 4 "sandwich_picture" column which contains the link to the picture.

Table_B will help to categorize the sandwiches:

- Column 1 called "sandwich_category" which corresponds with Column 3 from Table_A, contains the titles "Meatball Sandwich", "Turkey Sandwich"
- Column 2 "featured_sandwich_id" where I can select an ID of a sandwich from Table_A which I have a SELECT statement which pulls its featured image:

  ```
  SELECT featured_sandwich_id FROM Table_B WHERE sandwich_category='Meatball Sandwich' AND featured_sandwich_id != 0
  ```

I then have a if/while code which loads the featured sandwich image.

The issue I am having, is in some cases, there will be a new sandwich_type in Table_A which does not yet have its' own sandwich_category row in Table_B, in which case I want to have the code automatically pull image from the most recently inputted sandwich from Table_A. In other words, in the case that the featured_sandwich_id is not yet set in Table_B, I would like for the select statement to automatically pull the ID and image of the most recently posted sandwich from Table_A.

I'll try to be more specific and write out the procedure I would like the code to go through:

- 1 Auto-created div for each type of sandwich_category.
- 2: Div includes Table_B's sandwich_category name and checks if featured_sandwich_id has been set in Table_B.
- 3: If featured_sandwich_id has been set, pull the image associated with the sandwich id in Table_A.
- 4: If featured_sandwich_id has NOT been set (or if for some reason the sandwich_category has not yet been detailed in Table_B), use the sandwich_category name and image of the most recent sandwich from said sandwich_category, and populate them in the div above.

Here is my current code:

```
    $QUERY = "(
    SELECT Table_A.sandwich_picture, Table_A.sandwich_type, Table_B.featured_sandwich_id 
    FROM Table_A 
    LEFT JOIN Table_B 
    ON (Table_A.id = Table_B.featured_sandwich_id) 
    WHERE (Table_A.sandwich_type = 'Meatball Sandwich') 
    LIMIT 1)"
```

The above LEFT JOIN has an image for a 'Meatball Sandwich' and all other sandwich_types, but it is never the image for the associated featured_sandwich_id.

Switching the Statement above to a RIGHT JOIN always has the image for the featured_sandwich_id for 'Meatball Sandwich' and any other sandwich_type, but in the case that the featured_sandwich_id has not been set in the table, it pulls 0 results.

Here is the rest of the PHP as an example:

```
    ... while($query_results){

    echo '<div class="sandwich_category">
    <img src="$query_results['sandwich_picture']">
    <br>
    <p class="sandwich_category_name">';
    echo $query_results['sandwich_category']; // This is the category name
    echo '</p>
    </div>';

    }
```

As I understand it is best to condense into a single statement for the sake of saving resources, however I cant figure the correct type of join.

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: It seems to me that if you want to query the most recently added ID, you'd want to add a `date_added` DATETIME column to Table_A.

Comment: Thanks for the response - that could help, but the main issue is how to combine the tables in such a way that if there is no featured_sandwich_id set to pull an image from, then to pull the image from the most recently inputted sandwich ID that matches the sandwich_category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `LEFT JOIN`, `ORDER BY` and `DESC`:

```
SELECT b.sandwich_category, b.featured_sandwich_id, a.id, a.sandwich_name, a.sandwich_type, a.sandwich_picture
FROM Table_B b
LEFT JOIN Table_A a ON b.sandwich_category = a.sandwich_type
WHERE b.sandwich_category = 'Meatball Sandwich'
      AND b.featured_sandwich_id != 0 ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

What I just want to clarify is, you want to link those two tables by `Table_A`'s `sandwich_type` to `Table_B`'s `sandwich_category`, right? But the content of `Table_B`'s `sandwich_category` is in string. So that means `Table A`'s `sandwich_type` is a string?

Why not just link them by `Table_B`'s `primary id`? It will be much faster and reliable.

**UPDATE:**

```
SELECT b.sandwich_category, b.featured_sandwich_id, a.id, a.sandwich_name, a.sandwich_type, a.sandwich_picture
FROM Table_B b
LEFT JOIN Table_A a ON b.featured_sandwich_id = a.id
                    AND b.sandwich_category = a.sandwich_type
WHERE b.sandwich_category = 'Meatball Sandwich' AND b.featured_sandwich_id != 0 ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

Comment: I'll try to be more specific and write out the procedure I would like the code to go through: 1: Auto-created div for each type of sandwich_category. 2: Div will include sandwich_category name and image of featured_sandwich_id which has been set in Table_B, with the image data pulled from the matching sandwich ID in Table_A. 3: If there is no featured_sandwich_id set in Table_B or if the sandwich_category has not yet been created in Table_B, use the sandwich_category and most recently posted image of the sandwich from said sandwich_category. Sorry a bit confusing, I hope that helps.

Comment: I've updated the main post with easier formatting and better explanation :-)

Comment: @Chris - what does `Table B`'s `featured_sandwich_id` contain? Any `id` from `Table A`? Or just a `1` or `0` for trigger purposes?

Comment: @Chris I think you're having problem with your code because of your table structure. Maybe you should redo your table structure and schema.

Comment: Table B's featured_sandwich_id would contain any id from Table A, with Table A's ID corresponding with a specific sandwich. The problem I am having right now is that if I RIGHT JOIN Table B.featured_sandwich_id on Table A.id, it will pull the images of the featured_sandwich_id and display as intended, but any sandwich_category that does not have a specific featured_sandwich_id set does not show in the results.

Comment: If I LEFT JOIN Table B.featured_sandwich_id on Table A.id, it disregards the featured_sandwich_id completely and just shows an image of a sandwich from Table A that belongs to the sandwich_category of Table B... but, there is always an image. I need sort of a fallback method where if Table B does not have a featured_sandwich_id set for a sandwich_category, it will pull the most recent id from that sandwich_category instead, and load the image.

Comment: I could add sort of a 0 or 1 check on Table A that would designate any given sandwich as "featured" for its' related category, but that would prevent me from having one sandwich as the featured image for more than one sandwich_category, if I wanted to do that in the future. Would also be a bit harder to keep track of as there would be many more sandwiches than categories.